# Generate popular subjects from collection of post titles

Tags: php, algorithm, data-mining, data-processing

I have a content aggregator website. I'd like to process the post titles to generate a list of the most popular post subjects. A subject could be "software development" however an important point is that the two words "software" and "development" don't have to be directly next to each other in the post title.

The idea is to generate a list of possible collections (a group of posts that are based on the same subject)

I have started writing the code and have so far managed to generate a list of the most used words. Now I need to generate a new list ordered by number of occurrences of multiple words in post titles which I'm hoping would get me my final list of popular subjects.

Looking for help to finish this off. Added comments to my code to describe what I've done so far.

Also if anyone know a better way to do this please let me know!

```
/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function fire()
{
    $this->info('Starting...');

    // get last 1000 posts
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1000)->get();

    // create an array of post titles
    $titles_arr = array_map(function($n){
        return $n['title'];
    }, $posts->toArray());

    // create a big string of all the post titles
    $titles_str = implode(' ', $titles_arr);

    // create an array of the above string
    $words = explode(' ', strtolower($titles_str));

    // words to ignore
    $stopwords = array('a', 'about', 'above', 'across', 'after', 'afterwards', 'again', 'against', 'all', 'almost', 'alone', 'along', 'already', 'also','although','always','am','among', 'amongst', 'amoungst', 'amount',  'an', 'and', 'another', 'any','anyhow','anyone','anything','anyway', 'anywhere', 'are', 'around', 'as',  'at', 'back','be','became', 'because','become','becomes', 'becoming', 'been', 'before', 'beforehand', 'behind', 'being', 'below', 'beside', 'besides', 'between', 'beyond', 'bill', 'both', 'bottom','but', 'by', 'call', 'can', 'cannot', 'cant', 'co', 'con', 'could', 'couldnt', 'cry', 'de', 'describe', 'detail', 'do', 'done', 'down', 'due', 'during', 'each', 'eg', 'eight', 'either', 'eleven','else', 'elsewhere', 'empty', 'enough', 'etc', 'even', 'ever', 'every', 'everyone', 'everything', 'everywhere', 'except', 'few', 'fifteen', 'fify', 'fill', 'find', 'fire', 'first', 'five', 'for', 'former', 'formerly', 'forty', 'found', 'four', 'from', 'front', 'full', 'further', 'get', 'give', 'go', 'had', 'has', 'hasnt', 'have', 'he', 'hence', 'her', 'here', 'hereafter', 'hereby', 'herein', 'hereupon', 'hers', 'herself', 'him', 'himself', 'his', 'how', 'however', 'hundred', 'ie', 'if', 'in', 'inc', 'indeed', 'interest', 'into', 'is', 'it', 'its', 'itself', 'keep', 'last', 'latter', 'latterly', 'least', 'less', 'ltd', 'made', 'many', 'may', 'me', 'meanwhile', 'might', 'mill', 'mine', 'more', 'moreover', 'most', 'mostly', 'move', 'much', 'must', 'my', 'myself', 'name', 'namely', 'neither', 'never', 'nevertheless', 'next', 'nine', 'no', 'nobody', 'none', 'noone', 'nor', 'not', 'nothing', 'now', 'nowhere', 'of', 'off', 'often', 'on', 'once', 'one', 'only', 'onto', 'or', 'other', 'others', 'otherwise', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'out', 'over', 'own','part', 'per', 'perhaps', 'please', 'put', 'rather', 're', 'same', 'see', 'seem', 'seemed', 'seeming', 'seems', 'serious', 'several', 'she', 'should', 'show', 'side', 'since', 'sincere', 'six', 'sixty', 'so', 'some', 'somehow', 'someone', 'something', 'sometime', 'sometimes', 'somewhere', 'still', 'such', 'system', 'take', 'ten', 'than', 'that', 'the', 'their', 'them', 'themselves', 'then', 'thence', 'there', 'thereafter', 'thereby', 'therefore', 'therein', 'thereupon', 'these', 'they', 'thickv', 'thin', 'third', 'this', 'those', 'though', 'three', 'through', 'throughout', 'thru', 'thus', 'to', 'together', 'too', 'top', 'toward', 'towards', 'twelve', 'twenty', 'two', 'un', 'under', 'until', 'up', 'upon', 'us', 'very', 'via', 'was', 'we', 'well', 'were', 'what', 'whatever', 'when', 'whence', 'whenever', 'where', 'whereafter', 'whereas', 'whereby', 'wherein', 'whereupon', 'wherever', 'whether', 'which', 'while', 'whither', 'who', 'whoever', 'whole', 'whom', 'whose', 'why', 'will', 'with', 'within', 'without', 'would', 'yet', 'you', 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'the');

    // $words after stop words are filtered out
    $final_words = array_filter($words, function($n) use($stopwords){
        return (!in_array(strtolower($n), $stopwords));
    });

    // count occurence of array values
    $reduce = array_count_values($final_words);
    arsort($reduce); // sort

    // take first 1000 popular words
    $top_1000 = array_slice($reduce, 0, 1000);

    // I have the top 1000 used words. Now need to find which ones are present together the most (ordered)

    $matched_total = array();

    // for each post title
    foreach ($titles_arr as $title) {

        // split it into array
        $words = explode(' ', strtolower($title));

        $matched = array();

        echo $title . "\n";

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            // if in $top_1000 print and add to $matched array
            if(array_key_exists($word, $top_1000)) {
                echo $word . "\n";
                $matched[] = $word;
            }
        }

        // if contains popular words at to matched_total
        if(count($matched) > 0)
            $matched_total[] = $matched;        

    }

    // have the words that match for each post, now need to get which ones appear together the most

    $this->info('Finished.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that this shouldn't be done in PHP but here it goes anyway.

> 1. Remove non-stop words
> 2. For each  word keep track of which titles it appears in see
>      **title_keys** in the debug below
> 3. For each word, count the common titles between it and other words and store this count in the associative array (see
>      **count_other_word_in_same_title** in the debug output) and keep store all counts in a separate array so you know at the end of the loop how many times the top n phrase appears
> 4. Grab all phrases that appear >= the number of times the top n phrase appears and stop when you've grabbed n phrases

```
$titles = array(
    'where in the world is waldo',
    'software development for beginners',
    'waldo is travelling the world',
    'beginners learn to develop software',
    'the big brown dog jumped over waldo',
);

$stopwords = array('a', 'about', 'above', 'across', 'after', 'afterwards', 'again', 'against', 'all', 'almost', 'alone', 'along', 'already', 'also','although','always','am','among', 'amongst', 'amoungst', 'amount',  'an', 'and', 'another', 'any','anyhow','anyone','anything','anyway', 'anywhere', 'are', 'around', 'as',  'at', 'back','be','became', 'because','become','becomes', 'becoming', 'been', 'before', 'beforehand', 'behind', 'being', 'below', 'beside', 'besides', 'between', 'beyond', 'bill', 'both', 'bottom','but', 'by', 'call', 'can', 'cannot', 'cant', 'co', 'con', 'could', 'couldnt', 'cry', 'de', 'describe', 'detail', 'do', 'done', 'down', 'due', 'during', 'each', 'eg', 'eight', 'either', 'eleven','else', 'elsewhere', 'empty', 'enough', 'etc', 'even', 'ever', 'every', 'everyone', 'everything', 'everywhere', 'except', 'few', 'fifteen', 'fify', 'fill', 'find', 'fire', 'first', 'five', 'for', 'former', 'formerly', 'forty', 'found', 'four', 'from', 'front', 'full', 'further', 'get', 'give', 'go', 'had', 'has', 'hasnt', 'have', 'he', 'hence', 'her', 'here', 'hereafter', 'hereby', 'herein', 'hereupon', 'hers', 'herself', 'him', 'himself', 'his', 'how', 'however', 'hundred', 'ie', 'if', 'in', 'inc', 'indeed', 'interest', 'into', 'is', 'it', 'its', 'itself', 'keep', 'last', 'latter', 'latterly', 'least', 'less', 'ltd', 'made', 'many', 'may', 'me', 'meanwhile', 'might', 'mill', 'mine', 'more', 'moreover', 'most', 'mostly', 'move', 'much', 'must', 'my', 'myself', 'name', 'namely', 'neither', 'never', 'nevertheless', 'next', 'nine', 'no', 'nobody', 'none', 'noone', 'nor', 'not', 'nothing', 'now', 'nowhere', 'of', 'off', 'often', 'on', 'once', 'one', 'only', 'onto', 'or', 'other', 'others', 'otherwise', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'out', 'over', 'own','part', 'per', 'perhaps', 'please', 'put', 'rather', 're', 'same', 'see', 'seem', 'seemed', 'seeming', 'seems', 'serious', 'several', 'she', 'should', 'show', 'side', 'since', 'sincere', 'six', 'sixty', 'so', 'some', 'somehow', 'someone', 'something', 'sometime', 'sometimes', 'somewhere', 'still', 'such', 'system', 'take', 'ten', 'than', 'that', 'the', 'their', 'them', 'themselves', 'then', 'thence', 'there', 'thereafter', 'thereby', 'therefore', 'therein', 'thereupon', 'these', 'they', 'thickv', 'thin', 'third', 'this', 'those', 'though', 'three', 'through', 'throughout', 'thru', 'thus', 'to', 'together', 'too', 'top', 'toward', 'towards', 'twelve', 'twenty', 'two', 'un', 'under', 'until', 'up', 'upon', 'us', 'very', 'via', 'was', 'we', 'well', 'were', 'what', 'whatever', 'when', 'whence', 'whenever', 'where', 'whereafter', 'whereas', 'whereby', 'wherein', 'whereupon', 'wherever', 'whether', 'which', 'while', 'whither', 'who', 'whoever', 'whole', 'whom', 'whose', 'why', 'will', 'with', 'within', 'without', 'would', 'yet', 'you', 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'the');
$stopwords = array_flip($stopwords);
$allwords = array();

foreach($titles as $key => $title) {

    $words = explode(' ', strtolower($title));
    $words = array_unique($words); //optional

    foreach($words as $word) {

        if(isset($stopwords[$word]))
            continue;

        $allwords[$word]['title_keys'][$key] = $key;                
    }
}

print_r($allwords);

$copy_allwords = $allwords;
$counts = array();

//if you want to look for more than 2 word combos
//make this recursive
foreach($copy_allwords as $word => $stats) {        
    unset($copy_allwords[$word]);        
    foreach($copy_allwords as $word2 => $stats2) {
        $intersect = array_intersect_key($stats['title_keys'],$stats2['title_keys']);
        if(!empty($intersect)) {
            $allwords[$word]['count_other_word_in_same_title'][$word2] = count($intersect);
            $counts[] = count($intersect);
        }
    }
}

rsort($counts);    
$count_phrases = 2; // setting to retrieve top n phrases    
$phrases = array();

foreach($allwords as $word => $stats) {

    if(!isset($stats['count_other_word_in_same_title']))
        continue;

    foreach($stats['count_other_word_in_same_title'] as $other_word => $count) {
        if($count >= $counts[($count_phrases-1)]) {
            $phrases[$word . ' ' . $other_word] = $count;
            if(count($phrases) >= $count_phrases)
                break 2;
        }
    }
}

arsort($phrases);
print_r($phrases);
```

**Top 2 Phrases Output**

```
Array
(
    [software beginners] => 2 //2 = number of titles this phrase appears in
    [world waldo] => 2
)
```

**Contents of $allwords at the end**

```
Array
(
    [world] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [2] => 2
                )

            [count_other_word_in_same_title] => Array
                (
                    [waldo] => 2
                    [travelling] => 1
                )

        )

    [waldo] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [2] => 2
                    [4] => 4
                )

            [count_other_word_in_same_title] => Array
                (
                    [travelling] => 1
                    [big] => 1
                    [brown] => 1
                    [dog] => 1
                    [jumped] => 1
                )

        )

    [software] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                    [3] => 3
                )

            [count_other_word_in_same_title] => Array
                (
                    [development] => 1
                    [beginners] => 2
                    [learn] => 1
                    [develop] => 1
                )

        )

    [development] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [count_other_word_in_same_title] => Array
                (
                    [beginners] => 1
                )

        )

    [beginners] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                    [3] => 3
                )

            [count_other_word_in_same_title] => Array
                (
                    [learn] => 1
                    [develop] => 1
                )

        )

    [travelling] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [2] => 2
                )

        )

    [learn] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [3] => 3
                )

            [count_other_word_in_same_title] => Array
                (
                    [develop] => 1
                )

        )

    [develop] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [3] => 3
                )

        )

    [big] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 4
                )

            [count_other_word_in_same_title] => Array
                (
                    [brown] => 1
                    [dog] => 1
                    [jumped] => 1
                )

        )

    [brown] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 4
                )

            [count_other_word_in_same_title] => Array
                (
                    [dog] => 1
                    [jumped] => 1
                )

        )

    [dog] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 4
                )

            [count_other_word_in_same_title] => Array
                (
                    [jumped] => 1
                )

        )

    [jumped] => Array
        (
            [title_keys] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks FuzzyTree! This works well. Takes a loooong time to process but that may be what you mean by "I have a feeling that this shouldn't be done in PHP". Takes about 2minutes to process 3500 posts which I suppose isn't too bad

Comment: @iamjonesy try changing `array_intersect` to `array_intersect_key` that might speed things up a little

Comment: That does speed it up!